# Datagrid inside tooltip using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, tooltip, callouts

What will be the best approach to embed a datagridview like thing inside tooltip.

I would like to display useful information in an organized way inside tooltip control on MsChart rather than just displaying simple text info using callout or standard tooltip

I have tried using form as a tooltip but the main form gets focus lost when tooltip form is displayed.

Can anyone point me in right direction or give an approach which will be same in behavior as standard tooltip.

Thanks.

Comment: You can subclass the Chart Tooltip.
A test by using **SetWindowSubclass** and drawing anything in WM_PAINT (gradient + text for testing) =>
[Subclassed Chart Tooltip](https://i.ibb.co/SK6r3bm/Chart-Tooltip.gif)

Comment: I already tried this using image annotation class of mschart